# PHP Array Extraction

Tags: php, arrays, loops, extract

I have an array `$decoded` in PHP. Here's the the array :

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Ú 
  [1] => Ý 
  [2] => æ 
  [3] => â 
)
```

How can I `extract` the array and assign it into a variable?
I have tried to use `extract()` function, it works. **But my problem is** : the number of index of the array is dynamic. 
Any body want to help?

**UPDATE**

Here's my php trial :

```
<?php
$str = "admin";
echo $str."<br>";
$jc = strlen($str)-1;
for ($i=0;$i<=$jc;$i++){
echo $chr = substr($str,$i,1);
$an = ord($chr);
$asli = ord($chr);
if ($an >=65 and $an <= 90){
$an = $an+127;
}
if ($an >=97 and $an <= 122){
$an = $an+121;
}
if ($an >=48 and $an <= 57){
$an = $an+196;
}
if ($an == 32){
$an = 32;
}
   $decoded[$i] = chr($an);
   echo "  =>$asli => $an => ".$decoded[$i]."<br>";
}

?>
```

The result is :

```
admin
a =>97 => 218 => Ú
d =>100 => 221 => Ý
m =>109 => 230 => æ
i =>105 => 226 => â
n =>110 => 231 => ç
```

I want to assgin the decoded character (Ú,Ý,æ,â,ç) into a variable.
So, my goal is decode string `admin` to `ÚÝæâç`. As I said above, the variable `$str` is dynamic.

Comment: Can you show your code you've already written till now? For me it's not clear what you exactly want to do. Is this array in a PHP variable or as plain text?

Comment: First of all: why?! What problem are you trying to solve by extracting the array, and what do you expect the result to be if your problem is obviously that you can't predict the result?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.list.php

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: @RoyalBg Could be what he's looking for, but the number of elements is dynamic, so extract() fits more his needs.

Comment: You put it already in a variable $decoded don't you? So you can after your for loop do $myNewString = implode(NULL, $decoded) or concatinate the new chars to a string variable instead of creating an array and imploding it afterwards.

Comment: that's be an array @TiMESPLiNTER

Comment: See my updated comment above yours.

Comment: thanks for all your responses.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just concatenate the string:

```
<?php

$str = "admin";

echo $str."<br>";

$length = strlen($str);

$newstr = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    echo $chr = $str[$i];

    $an = ord($chr);

    if ($an >=65 and $an <= 90) {
        $an = $an+127;
    }

    if ($an >=97 and $an <= 122) {
        $an = $an+121;
    }

    if ($an >=48 and $an <= 57) {
        $an = $an+196;
    }
    if ($an == 32) {
        $an = 32;
    }

    $newstr .= chr($an);
}

echo $newstr;
```

Comment: But i have a problem with character "." in `$newstr.= chr($an)`. json would read it as an error, so json said : unexpected character.

Comment: if you want this to be json, you have to encode it `echo json_encode($newstr);`

Comment: that's not what i meant. I think i should have a discuss with you

Comment: I'm there waiting for you.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this, it will create array of your varibale:

```
$array = Array ( 
  [0] => Ú 
  [1] => Ý 
  [2] => æ 
  [3] => â 
);
extract($array, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
$defined_vars = get_defined_vars(); 
print_r($defined_vars);
```

I know this is not exactly what you looking for, but can get some idea from this.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i think kelunik's answer is easier to do, and it works. :D

Answer (score 1):

I just add something. You will meet some problems when you convert character that is not usual character.
I have try your script. Your character will be doubled or sparated by an unsual character, and the ASCII number(64) will be subtracted by 64, so you have sum it by 64 to get your character.
here's the solution:

```
        $pwd = "AzsOke";
        $jc = strlen($pwd)-1;
        for ($i=0;$i<=$jc;$i++){
            if ( $i%2 == 1){
                $chr = substr($pwd,$i,1);
                $an = ord($chr);
                $asli = ord($chr);
                if ($an >=193 and $an <= 217){
                    $an = $an-127;
                }
                if ($an >=218 and $an <= 243){
                    $an = $an-121;
                }
                if ($an >=244 and $an <= 253){
                    $an = $an-196;
                }
                if ($an == 32){
                    $an = 32;
                }
                $codenumber_pwd .= $an+64;                       
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ah thank you, it's the matter i found after. But i have another solution, force it to ASCII.